Why CustomEvent remains unhandled in JS code
I'm trying to fire up a custom event and catch it by a child element, which doesn't seem to work. What am I missing (I am aware of DOM-less solutions, but need to get it working with DOM)?
I tried a few different options including swapping child and parent to eliminate potential bubbling/tunneling issues, and tried the legacy Event class, but none seemed to work.


document.getElementById("parent").addEventListener("click", function() {
  window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("test", {
    detail: "Hello"
  }));
});



document.getElementById("child").addEventListener("test", function(event) {
  console.info("Hello");
});
<button id="parent">Fire</button>
<div id="child" />




You fire the event on window, so it won't travel down to trigger the event on child. It only bubbles up the tree.

Also the parent and child element are not really parent and child, despite the names. They are both siblings on the same level.

why can't I use custom events the same way I'd use "click" event for example?

You can? You just run in the exact same limitations as a click event. If you decide to dispatch a click on window it will also not traverse down the DOM. Only bubbles up but window is the top level anyway.

Sure, too much WPF I suppose, some framework allow for the event propagations downwards (called tunneling). This is quite useful when working with event sourcing, for instance.

The issue is because you've assigned the test event listener to the #child element, but you're triggering it against the window.
To fix the problem, listen for the event on the element you raise it on, or one of its parents.


const parent = document.querySelector('#parent');
const child = document.querySelector('#child');

parent.addEventListener("click", () => {
  child.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("test", {
    detail: "Hello"
  }));
});

child.addEventListener("test", e => {
  console.info(e.detail);
});
<button id="parent">Fire</button>
<div id="child" />




Ouch. I missed out on the concept completely. I thought that I can use Events as a vehicle for delivering some arbitrary data down/up the DOM tree without knowing the actual receivers. Needing to know the receiver makes it pretty much meaningless as in that case I'd rather call the receiver's method directly w/out messing with events.
